# Skip x elements on an object collection in PHP using (or not) Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I've got an object collection and I want to take n elements, after skiping x elements. To explain my problem, I will use my collection **$teachers** a collection of object from a class teacher. I'm using PHP 5.4 and Laravel 4 Framework (I'm ready to use PHP functions, or Laravel's if it exists).

I know this collection contains 40 teachers. I want to take from this collection 10 teachers after skiping 5. I'm looking for something like array_slice.

Edit: I've removed the example as I think it didn't help as much as expected to present my problem. My bad..

Comment: It's not even a valid php

Comment: What do you mean by it's not a valid php? If you talk about ->take or -> count it's from my Laravel framework. I'm ready to use functions from the framework or not

Comment: `$teachers = [{id : 12},{id : 23},{id : 34},{id : 45},{id : 56}];` <--- this line is not a valid php. We have no idea what exactly `$teachers` is in your code

Comment: @Sébastien Renauld: please be more careful and finally note that it still requires: 1. quoted key names 2. `=>` not `:` 3. Introducing short array syntax doesn't imply there is a short objects creation syntax `{...}`. Thank you :-)

Comment: @zerkms: Correct on that front, his objects are not correctly defined (even assuming they are objects). The outer array format still remains valid, though, and there is no ambiguity on $teachers, merely its contents.

Comment: @Sébastien Renauld: "and there is no ambiguity on $teachers, merely its contents" --- well, if I'm given syntactically incorrect code I'd rather will not make **any** assumptions at all. At the moment the whole question doesn't make much sense. Because uhm, how would you explain the next line `$teachers->count() Will return 5` ? Do php objects provide any methods? So it would return a fatal error, not `5`

Comment: Well on the first lines I explained that $teachers (in bold) is my object collection. The 2 lines of "codes" is just an example. I'm going to update my question

Comment: @jibe_84: "is my object collection" --- it doesn't expose its type explicitly. PHP doesn't provide neither a single unique "a collection" class nor an interface.

Comment: I removed the example as it didn't help as expected..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$partial = $teachers->slice(5, 10);
```

If `$teachers` is a native array, use this:

```
array_slice($teachers, 5, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function skip($arr, $no_to_skip)
{
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $no_to_skip; $i++) 
    {
        array_shift($arr);
    }
    return $arr;
}
```